# WCAG guidelines (CSS+HTML+Javascript)

Tags: html, css, accessibility, wcag

How can I make sure my web site follows the WCAG guidelines and works reasonably for users with low-bandwidth connections?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a [primer on WCAG from the W3C](http://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/wcag).

Your best bet is to run your site through these validators:

- [W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/)
- [Wave Accessibility Evaluation Tool](http://wave.webaim.org/)
- [W3C CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)

It's a good practice to follow the guidelines of the W3C when coding a website. If you follow their suggestions, you're usually set in terms of accessibility.

Look through this list of [web accessibility evaluation tools](http://www.w3.org/WAI/RC/tools/complete).

As an extra resource, follow some of these guidelines for low bandwidth sites:

- [Web Design Guidelines for Low Bandwidth](http://www.aptivate.org/webguidelines/Tools.html)

Answer (score 0):

WCAG is a series of web accessibility guidelines published  by W3C.

There are 3 levels of WCAG 2.0 specifications.
1. WCAG Single Level A,
2. WCAG Double Level A.
3. WCAG Triple Level A

[image]

These are some of the tips for making sure that our site is WCAG compliant

- Label  all form elements
- Provide alternate text for non-text content. This would help people who are blind with assistance technology which can announce to them.People who are blind can use screen readers like 
  VoiceOver is inbuilt in mac,
  NVDA and JAWS has to be downloaded for windows
  ,Chrome browser has chromevox

for more information you can look at this article [enter link description here](http://www.prathapkudupublog.com/2017/05/overview-of-wcag.html)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with running the tools suggested. However, these tools will not get you to an fully compliant site, usually far from it. You need to make sure that the site is completely operable by the keyboard.  You need to make sure that the alternative text you provide is meaningful and that links are labeled in a way the provide context and purpose. You should read up on WAI-ARIA.  The subject is more complex than people realize. WCAG is a usability standard and if your site has any complexity at all the automated tools will let you down.